# JavaFX open new window issue with fxml

Tags: java, javafx

I'm developing a password manager program. When opening a new window in this program it throws an exception on the `addEntry()` mouse click event. I have a `Main` class that opens the main window (with `sample.fxml`) and a `Controller` class that manages to open the new window (with `addNewEntryDialog.fxml`). Here's my code:

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Password Manager");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {
    public ObservableList<Data> data;
    public TableView dbTable;
    public TableColumn siteColumn, usernameColumn, passwordColumn;

    public ToggleButton showPasswordToggle;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        fillTable();
    }

    public void fillTable(){
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM accounts";

        try {
            Connection connection = connectToDatabase();
            ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(query);

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                data.add(new Data(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2), resultSet.getString(3)));
            }

            siteColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("site"));
            usernameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("username"));
            passwordColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("password"));

            dbTable.setItems(data);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void addEntry() throws IOException {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/addEntryDialog.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("Add new entry");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        stage.show();
    }
```

addEntryDialog.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <GridPane layoutX="28.0" layoutY="21.0" prefHeight="123.0" prefWidth="317.0">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="33.0" layoutY="26.0" text="Site:" />
            <Label layoutX="28.0" layoutY="78.0" text="Username:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label layoutX="44.0" layoutY="135.0" text="Password:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <TextField fx:id="siteField" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="21.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <TextField fx:id="usernameField" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="73.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="123.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <Button layoutX="327.0" layoutY="163.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="OK" />
      <Button layoutX="246.0" layoutY="163.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cancel" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<Pane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="dbTable" layoutX="4.0" layoutY="85.0" prefHeight="505.0" prefWidth="790.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="siteColumn" prefWidth="263.0" text="Site" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="usernameColumn" prefWidth="263.0" text="Username" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="passwordColumn" prefWidth="263.0" text="Password" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <GridPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="263.0">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="addNewEntry" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#addEntry" text="Add.." GridPane.columnIndex="0" />
            <Button fx:id="removeEntry" layoutX="83.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Remove.." GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <Button fx:id="editEntry" layoutX="178.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit.." GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <ToggleButton fx:id="showPasswordToggle" layoutX="671.0" layoutY="27.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show Password" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

STACK TRACE

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/umberto/passwordManager/out/production/passwordManager/addEntryDialog.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at sample.Controller.addEntry(Controller.java:58)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Controller.loadTableData(Controller.java:45)
    at sample.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:30)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: it gives many exception errors when calling the addEntry() method (mouse clicked event)

Comment: so add the stack trace to your question.

Comment: You haven't included the sample.fxml/addEntryDialog.fxml files or the actual error message/stack trace, so it's impossible to say what the problem is. You should create a snippet of your application that is actually runnable, so refactor out the database code and include the Data domain object as well. Just the stack trace alone will help immensely though.

Comment: ok, I'm going to add the stack trace and the fxml files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `addEntryDialog.fxml` file. There is definition of this view's controller:

```
<Pane ... fx:controller="sample.Controller>
```

JavaFX loads the view, looks for the controller and creates it. (At this moment another `sample.Controller` object is instantiated). After creating it sees that this controller implements `Initializable` interface, so it executes `initialize` method which in turn calls `fillTable` method and finally the statement `siteColumn.setCellValueFactory(..)` is reached. The problem is that there's no `siteColumn` for `addEntryDialog.fxml` view - it has not been bound since there's no element on view with that id.

Solution is to create proper controller for `addEntryView.fxml` and call it in xml `fx:controller` attribute.

Comment: I only need addEntryView.fxml when clicking an "Add" button to add a new table entry, siteColumn is part of the table. So I only need to open a new window from a method, I don't care about table columns.

Comment: @UmbertoPalazzini That's right, but you have defined `sample.Controller` as the controller of `addEntryView` dialog. This is why it throws null pointer exception. Creating new window involves creating controller for it, controller is created and throws NPE during initialization because there're no columns on `addEntryView`.